I am facing an issue while working with OpenAI model for text summarization
Every time I try to run this error show up:

error occurred during summarization: "You exceeded your current quota,
please check your plan and billing details. For more information on
this error, read the docs:
https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/error-codes/api-errors.

(i have tried changing model and creating new api-key too)
Here is my code:
    import openai
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")

if not openai.api_key:
    raise ValueError("API key not found. Set the OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable.")


def openai_summarizer(text):
    try:
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
            model="davinci-002"
            messages=[
                {
                    "role": "system",
                    "content": "You are a helpful assistant that summarizes text.",
                },
                {"role": "user", "content": text},
            ],
            max_tokens=150,
            temperature=0.5,
        )
        summary = response.choices[0].message["content"].strip()
        return summary
    except Exception as e:
        return f"Error occurred during summarization: {str(e)}"

                 

I have tried changing to different available models and creating new api-key too.

After you created a new api key, did you set it in the environment?
